# Nuxt Vue2 Application, Adding Vue-Touch Package

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to get xy-coordinate data for a touch 'pan' event, where a user presses their finger down and drags it. I am using Vue2 with Nuxt and trying to add the [Vue-Touch Package](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-touch).

I installed the package with npm and then added a plugin to my Nuxt setup by adding a 'touch' folder to the 'plugins' folder, including an 'index.js' file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'; 
import VueTouch from 'vue-touch';
Vue.use(VueTouch, {name: 'v-touch'});
export { VueTouch };
export default VueTouch;
```

Then, I made an element `<v-touch v-on:tap="myClickEvent">My Element</v-touch>` in the page that I want the canvas to be. I am trying to register a tap event to make sure that the package is working properly before I move on to the pan.

When I run my project, I get two errors:

```
[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

&

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <v-touch> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Any suggestions for getting my Vue-Touch package to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add config to `plugins` section of `nuxt.config.js` file?

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [{
    src: '~plugins/touch',
    ssr: false
  }]
}
```